# Win7- Are msconfig options in Safe Mode the same as those shown in Normal bootup?

Tags: windows-7-x64, boot

I changed some of the options in msconfig (while in normal bootup), most notably of which was changing from a selective startup to normal..  it was after that initial reboot that my problems occurred, but that's not why I'm here.

However, for background/troubleshooting purposes: the other changes should all be just fine (just removed a couple of programs from startup), such as adobe reader. I'm not worried about those, but I am worried the changing of "selective startup" may have directly led to my current situation (again, not why I'm here, but feel free to chip in) -> and *that problem* is simply: the screen goes dark immediately after the win7 login screen appears (the computer is still running, I can't tell if I can login or not)... I digress..

**I just want to know if the configuration values for msconfig are the same between safe mode and when operating normally in windows 7.**

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are the same, but they are not treated the same in safe mode. For example, all the startup applications show up in msconfig in safe mode and normal mode, but they're not loaded in safe mode.

Comment: Just wondering about those config values for selective startup. It was the only thing I could think of at the time. I fixed my other issues, which were caused by my original suspicions around deselecting "selective startup".  It appears as though it just disabled all of my services when I clicked Normal and reboot.  Not sure why though.